# Hotelling T squared seemingly useless at detecting a mean shift

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution, quality-control, hotelling-t2

I am trying to develop a single-sample Hotelling $T^2$ test in order to implement a multivariate control chart, as described in Montgomery, D. C. (2009) Introduction To Statistical Quality Control, chapter 11.3.2. In this chapter, Montgomery defines $T^2 = (\mathbf{x} - \bar{\mathbf{x}})^TS^{-1}(\mathbf{x} - \bar{\mathbf{x}})$, where $\bar{\mathbf{x}}$ is the sample mean and $\mathbf{S}$ is the sample covariance matrix, and $\mathbf{x}$ (I believe) is the sample value at a single timepoint (would be better notated as $\mathbf{x}_i$ I think).

Anyway, the point of the control chart is that it's a kind of "continuous hypothesis test" that plots the test statistic over time, and whenever the statistic gets too high we suspect the mean of the distribution has shifted. For a simple summary of this, please refer to https://www.spcforexcel.com/knowledge/variable-control-charts/hotelling-t2-control-chart.

With the help of the `qcc` package, I am trying to implement this in R. However I have noticed that this statistic is totally useless at detecting mean shifts. For this reason I wonder if I am doing something wrong. In this code I generate a sample dataset, and plot it:

```r
require('tidyverse')

set.seed(1)

df = rerun(10, c(rnorm(50, 0), rnorm(50, 10))) %>%
  bind_cols() %>%
  mutate(index=1:100)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(!index) %>%
  ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=index, y=value, color=name))
```

[image]

So, there's obviously a shift in the mean. Now if I calculate the continuous test statistic:

```r
require('qcc')
# Calculate the T2 statistic as defined above
t2 = df %>%
  select(!index) %>%
  stats.T2.single()

# Plot it
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=1:100, y=t2$statistics)) + geom_line(aes(x=1:100, y=t2$statistics))
```

[image]

The statistic doesn't at all correlate with the changes in the mean! It seems to peak at 95 instead of 50, where the distribution changes. What's happening here?

Comment: Are you calculating $T^2$ & its control limits with $\bar x$ & $S$ derived from the whole data-set? I'm not familiar with this software package, but there should be two stages to control analysis: calculating the control limit from the process when it's in control, & then monitoring it to see if $T^2$ (calculated with the in-control parameter estimates) crosses that limits. If you calculate the control limit from a wildly out-of-control process, then of course it'll be too high to detect its being out of control.

Comment: The answer comes down to understanding what `mqcc` actually does.  You need to explain this function.

Comment: It might help to consider what would happen in the univariate case: the variance estimate would be inflated by the pooling of samples from two sub-populations with different means, pushing up the control limit; & the mean estimate would be about mid-way between the means of the sub-population, so that the *squared* deviations would have a similar distribution throughout.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica I have removed the control limits as they are not relevant to my question. I am just interested in how the T2 statistic does or does not reflect the mean shift (which yes, will affect whether or not it crosses the control limits)

Comment: @whuber I have removed the `mqcc` function call. Instead I only use the `qcc` library for its implementation of the T2 statistic.

Comment: Thanks! - I've re-opened it. (I think the answer's basically what I said in comments, though needing some elaboration.)

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica even if I make the segment after the mean shift have `n=10`, the statistic still doesn't help. In that situation the mean of the first segment should make up the majority of the overall mean.